# Disk write 5 sec. timeout

Tags: .net, vb.net

I can't solve this problem long time, and I can't find a solution anywhere.

When I want to write some file to local disk, it's done after few milliseconds.
But when I want to write another file to disk, the application freezes for 5 seconds + few milliseconds.

After that it doesn't happen again.
It's always the second write to disk and it's always exactly 5 more seconds.

Doesn't matter if I use

```vb
System.IO.File.Copy(file1, file2)
```

or

```vb
bmp(0).Save(name & "_CCTV.jpg")
```

Comment: Disable your antivirus and try again?

Comment: You'd probably want to use multithreading to get around this, it doesn't fix the root cause but it does get around it.

Comment: @AStopher surely TAP would be easier?

Comment: Two rather different ways of writing to disk there; probably not the code's fault - try a different disk?

Comment: As a side note, this: `bmp(0).Save(name & "_CCTV.jpg")` produces a PNG image, not a JPEG image. The *extension* is irrelevant, you didn't provide an `ImageFormat`, so the default is used. The default is PNG. + You should clearly define what `file1`, `file2` contain. You should (but read *must*) specify a full path, not just a file name, hoping that the new file will end up where your executable is located. This is not, even remotely, reliable.